# "His" or "My" when describing who I am

Tags: pronouns

I am wondering which of the below sentence is correct...

(if there are other errors, please point them out as well)

> It is because of these experiences that make me who I am today, a leader who is nominated not only for **his** impact in **his** community, but also for **his** excellence in sports.
>
> It is because of these experiences that make me who I am today, a leader who is nominated not only for **my** impact in **my** community, but also for **my** excellence in sports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun's antecedent is "a leader." So, "his," of course – the backward reference is to "a leader," not to the earlier "me" or "I."